# Office Communicator 2007 (MOC): How to make chat history visible to newcomers

Tags: instant-messaging

How can someone who joins an existing Microsoft Communicator chat see the history of what has gone before?

For example:

---

```
Larry: [describes problem]
Moe: [enhances problem]
Curly: We should ask Shemp

[Shemp joins]
Shemp: What's going on in this thread?
```

---

Is there any way for Shemp to see what Larry and Moe have already typed?

I have tried copy-pasting the whole thing, but that invokes an error with no error message - possibly "too much text."

Update:

Is this functionality what Microsoft calls Group Chat, and requires a separate product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to do this.

Group chat would solve this problem, but the users would have to join a chat channel, they could not just start a conversation.  Also keep in mind Group chat may require additional infrastructure, it also requires a separate group chat client and administration can be a burden.